# Перенос виртуального диска vhdx в физический

Tags: windows, hyper-v, виртуальная-машина

В Hyper-V под Windows 2012 R2 есть виртуальная машина, используется виртуальный диск vhdx.
Возникла необходимость использовать физический диск вместо виртуального.
Каким образом можно перенести данные с диска vhdx на физический?

Comment: Отключить виртуальную машину. Смонтировать копированный vhdx на рабочую машину. Подключить физический диск  рабочей машине. Клонировать диск с использованием любых доступных платных или бесплатных решений.

Comment: @Daemon-5, а если внутри образа Linux?

Comment: Не принципиально, большинство утилит поддерживают работу с известными FAT, на худой конец можно посекторно клонировать. Есть даже WIndows-версия **dd**

Comment: Clonezilla. Умеет с железки на железку по сети минуя образы. В твоём случае - то, что надо.

Comment: @don Rumata, да именно так и сделал, в виртуалке загрузился с нее. При переносе образа клонированием с диска на диска итоговая система не хотела загружаться. Сделал 3-й диск, туда записал файл образа исходного диска, из образа восстановил, система оказалась загрузочной.